# Xcode file templates aren't created correctly

Tags: xcode, xcode-template

I'm having an issue with custom file templates in Xcode 4.

For example, with the cocos2d templates, when I try to make a new CCLayer file called GameLayer at my project root, it generates the files at `.xctemplate/CCLayer/Gamelayer.h` and `.xctemplate/CCLayer/Gamelayer.m`

[image]

The files seem to be correct but they're in the wrong place and they weren't added to the project.

I've tried this with the Cocos2d file templates as well as the Kiwi template from [this post](http://objvimmer.com/blog/2011/10/05/kiwi-xcode-file-template/). Also any templates I try to create myself seem to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was being caused by the fact that my ~/Libary/Developer/ was a symlink to a different drive to save space on my SSD. Whatever Xcode does when creating files from templates has problems with symlinks.